# Does this reformat my hard drive?

Tags: system-installation

I am thinking of changing from Win8 to Ubuntu and am nervous because I do not want to lose my data I have currently. Does this reformat my drive?

Comment: possible duplicated [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the options you choose.

If you are proficient in Windows you could shrink your Windows partition and create unallocated space enough for your Ubuntu needs. This is by far the easiest method and least error prone for installing any OS for a dual setup.

During installation of Ubuntu you then will be prompted where to install and among the options it will list "use unallocated space".

But of course you need not to worry since you start by making a backup of anything important ;-)